# How can i parse text from string and add it to a List<string> using indexof and substring?

Tags: c#, .net

The code:

```
int index = 0;
List<string> Names = new List<string>();
while (index != -1)
{
    string firstTag = "a title";
    string endTag = "href";
    string forums = webBrowser1.DocumentText;
    index = forums.IndexOf(firstTag);
    int index1 = forums.IndexOf(endTag, index);
    string Count = forums.Substring(index + 9, ((index1 - 35) - index));
    Names.Add(forumsCount);
}
```

In this case i want to use indexof and substring.
The way i did it now i'm getting endless loop and very large List Names and all the Names inside is the same one the index is never move forward.

Comment: i take it it's a html document?

Comment: also please add some example data + expected output

Comment: The infinite loop is due to you never setting `index` to `-1`.

Comment: The infinite loop is due to that webBrowser1.DocumentText always contains "a title".

Comment: parsing data out of a html document using string functions is kinda like to fight a dragon naked with a toothpick ... I'd look up html agility pack and get this done in a way more safe manner

Comment: @DanielShabos Your code is unclear... What does `forums` variable store, where it gets its' value?

Comment: Yes it was my mistake the variable is forums

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you never move forward the starting point. You need to use **IndexOf(String, Int32)** when getting the first index and specify where to start the search, otherwise you'll just keep getting the same result.

Something like this:

```
const string openingTag = "a title=\"";
const string closingTag = "\" href";

var html = " sadsffdaf a title=\"מכבי תאמכ\" href, a title=\" תאמכ\" href, a title=\"מכבי \" href";

var names = new List<string>();

var index = 0;
var previousIndex = 0;

while (index > -1)
{
    index = html.IndexOf(openingTag, previousIndex);

    if (index == -1)
        continue;

    var secondIndex = html.IndexOf(closingTag, index);

    var result = html.Substring(index + openingTag.Length, secondIndex - (index + openingTag.Length));
    names.Add(result);

    previousIndex = index + 1;
}
```

**EDIT:** I updated code to include an example HTML string I tested against as per your comment.

I also updated the substring to get the text between the two tags. I assume this is what you want to do?

Also, in your question you're taking the first index from 'nums' and the second tag from 'forums'. I'm guessing this was a typo?

I'm not sure I can help any further without seeing the actual HTML you are parsing.

Comment: RagtimeWilly this is example of string i want to extract from a title="מכבי ת``א" href what i want to get is the text inside: מכבי ת``א in the solution you gave the first time the first iteration it's working good and i see in Names the first name. But then in the next iteration i'm getting other text not the name i wanted and in the fourth iteration i'm getting exception on the line: string forumsCount = forums.Substring(index + 9, ((index1 - 35) - index)); Length cannot be less than zero.

Comment: My answer just explains why you were getting the same result over and over in an infinite loop. It's quite difficult to explain the cause of the other issues without seeing the HTML you are parsing. Also, it sounds like your substring calculation is incorrect.

Comment: @DanielShabos I updated answer in response to the additional information you provided. I hope this helps get you on the right track.

Comment: RagtimeWilly it does work almost perfect. I'm getting 204 or so results and items in my List. The problem is that the first three items in the List are not good. For example the first item index 0 is: רישום לתפוז אנשים" class="registerMessage and the second item is: כניסה למערכת" class="loginMessage" onclick="showLoginPopup()">כניסה למערכת</a></span><span class="last"><a title="facebook" id="TapuzConnectWelcomeHeaderBtn" class="loginFacebook and the third index is: facebook" id="TapuzConnectWelcomeHeaderBtn" class="loginFacebook and then from here the rest of items are fine.

Comment: Ragtime you can see the html text file content here: http://pastebin.com/K2vE9Ryh

Comment: Ragtime you right my mistake. The variable is forums i updated my question changed it to forums.

Comment: @DanielShabos This is because there's three link titles that don't seem to be part of the pattern you are trying to match before the main set of links. If you want to skip them start the index at the point you want to start matching patterns from: `var index = html.IndexOf("<div class=\"CatLinkContainer\">");` and `var previousIndex = index;`

Comment: This type of parsing is very imperfect and fragile. If this is how you want to do it you just have to try to deal with these issues as they arise. If you need the first three anomalous links just turn the above code into a method with the tags as arguments and pass in the three other sets of tags to match those link titles correctly.